# Why do we prefer byte[] against int[] or long[]?

Tags: java, primitive-types

This might be so simple question,

I know that `byte` is a primitive type in `java`, that belongs to `integer` family and requires `1 byte` of space in the memory. When we deal with binary data(for example when we read/write a file), we store the data into `byte array` and we do operations, Here my doubt is when we have other primitives like `short,int` why do we prefer `byte[]`? Could anyone clarify

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with a byte array is practically (ignoring computers that cannot work with 8-bit chunks of data natively; I don't even know if such exist in actual use these days) guaranteed to always represent the data bytes in the same order, regardless of platform, programming language or framework. Given knowledge of the storage or transmission format, you can translate it to whatever internal format your current platform etc. uses.

For example, I wouldn't trust that an application written in C++ running on an Alpha CPU will write out an `unsigned long` in the same way that a .NET application running on Intel writes out a `UInt32` (let alone how perhaps Java running on an IBM z10 might handle the lower 32 bits of a 64-bit `long` or PIC assembly might handle tossing a 32-bit value at an I/O port). If you work with pure bytes, this becomes a non-issue: you will have to translate the byte sequence wherever you read or write it, but you will know exactly how to do that. It is *well defined*.

If you send data over a socket, persist it to a file, or otherwise transmit it in space or time, by using a byte array you guarantee that the recipient will see exactly what was sent or persisted. It is then up to the recipient (note that the "recipient" may be your own application's file "load" code, whereas the "sender" may be the code to "save" to a file) to do something useful with the byte sequence that the sender generated from whatever happens to be its native format.

If you are using non-byte types, you need to guarantee the byte order by other means, because depending on platform etc. the bytes may be interpreted in a different order. For example, you would need to specify (either yourself or by reference to the framework's specification) whether the persisted form of a multi-byte integer uses big endian or little endian.

Comment: I don't see how using a byte[] helps if you need to send an `int` or a `double` You just have to do the byte order yourself and you have the same problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If you can limit yourself to specifying the byte order and let anyone who uses a different byte order do all the bitshifting, it isn't an issue. The byte order specification can be either implicit (reference to framework etc) or explicit, but it needs to be there. If you convert your data to `byte[]` before writing it out to wherever, and performance isn't critical (because admittedly doing so takes non-zero time), you know exactly what the byte order is just looking at the code that writes it out. If you need compatibility between architectures this can be a big point.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling You mean except byte, all other primitive types are converted(modify the byte format) into the framework specific byte formats?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the Java class library does it, but from a programming point of view what matters in storage is sequences of bytes. One big (and the one I claim in my answer) advantage to reading and writing bytes directly is that you know exactly which order they (will) appear in in the I/O data when it gets to your code or hits storage. Of course that holds true if you are working with e.g. `int` too (just check the specification), but *it isn't guaranteed to be the same everywhere*. I wouldn't trust C++ on Alpha to write out a `long` the same way .NET on Intel does a `UInt32`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: If one needs to send an `int`, the intended recipient is going to expect to receive the resulting bytes in some sequence.  If the recipient expects to receive data MSB first, then that is the order in which it must be sent, *independent of how anybody's machine actually stores integers*.

Answer (score 2):

Streams like files and sockets are modelled as bytes i.e. byte[].  There are some file formats which are actually 16-bit values or 32-bit value etc but these are natives just bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a 100MB file and read it into an array of `int` you would need 400MB of memory (if you read one byte into each element - you *could* pack 4 bytes into one int but it would be very difficult to work with individual bytes that way). So outright memory efficiency is one reason I'd say, on top of the reason that bytes are the fundamental smallest addressable unit of memory of almost all computer systems today.

Comment: Why would you need 400 MB of memory to read a 100 MB file as a set of `int`? Assuming a 32-bit `int`, just read four bytes into each `int`. The memory usage then comes out the same. Of course, if you read each *byte* into an `int`, that's a different matter, but then you are still dealing with bytes, just keeping them in a wider type internally.

Comment: Yes I just edited. If you pack 4 bytes into one int, working with individual bytes would become a little bit of a headache right? :)

Comment: @WayneUroda You mean we can even use int[] and long[]. if storage is not an issue?

Comment: If you need to work with the individual bytes, then you'd read the data into a `byte[]` rather than an `int[]`. That certain languages lack types which can express certain ranges and nothing more (like Java not having a type that can express exactly the range 0..255 inclusive) to my mind only serves to reinforce this point if the goal is portability of the stored data.

Comment: @WayneUroda Your point is, to achieve portability among different programming languages or different machines or different unicode formats across the globe, we prefer byte[]. isn't it so?

Comment: @MaheshVarma not really the point I'm trying to make - if there was only one computer in existence we'd probably still program it with bytes and byte arrays when it comes to working with chunks of memory (i.e. anything other than doing math) - but there is no fundamental rule of nature that says it had to be 8 bits == 1 byte, we could have ended up with 10 bit computers. I would guess that 8bits was a tradeoff between numeric range and circuit complexity in early computers?

Answer (score 0):

byte is the unit of measure of the size of binary transfer. If you do not use byte, then, for example, yo can not reliably send a 1 byte message, read a 3 byte file, etc.

Another factor is protocols like utf8, where data sequences are not aligned on a fixed-size byte boundary.

Comment: Admittedly, UTF-8 is no more a protocol than SMTP is a data encoding or WWW is an operating system. :)

Answer (score -1):

**COMMON USAGE AMONG**

> Many types of applications use information representable in eight or fewer bits and processor designers optimize for this common usage. The popularity of major commercial computing architectures has aided in the ubiquitous acceptance of the 8-bit size.

Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte